# Why is it possible to use a non-static method inside a class method without an object but impossible to do inside the Main method if it's also inside

Tags: java, methods, static, program-entry-point

Why is it possible to use a **non-static** method inside the class it's been created **without** an object but impossible to do **inside the Main method** if it's **also** inside the class for example :

```
public class C {
    public void f() {...};
    
    public void g() { f() }; //no error
    
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        f(); //compilation error.
    }
}
```

Comment: inside g `f()` is the short for `this.f()`

Comment: In order for you to syntactically/legally call `f()` or `g()` there has already been a constructor called somewhere before then (i.e. you can only call `instanceOfC.f()`, or `instanceOfC.g()`.  A static method can be called without first constructing an instance of the class, so calls no non-static methods would cause a problem.  And, as Turo mentioned, it's assumed that when you call an instance method from a within a class, you're calling it on the current instance (i.e. `this`)

Answer (score 1):

Inside an instance of a class, there is an implicit `this` when invoking methods in it.

```
public class C {

    public void f() { }
    public void g() {
        this.f(); // not a compile-time error; this refers to an instance of C
    }
}
```

Inside a static method, there *is* no `this` because static methods have no instance attached to them, thus it would be a compile-time error to try to refer to it.

From [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2):

> A class method is always invoked without reference to a particular object. It is a compile-time error to attempt to reference the current object using the keyword this (§15.8.3) or the keyword super (§15.11.2).

So in the static method, you need an instance of `C` to invoke `f`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new C().f();
}
```

Comment: In short: heed the words of "As Time Goes By", famously heard in the film Casablanca: you must remember **this**,